# Command line arguments to ocamldebug

Tags: debugging, ocaml, ocamldebug

How can I pass command line arguments to ocaml debugger?  I am looking for something similar to gdbs `--args`, or `r ...`, or `params ... <`.  For example, after compiling

```
open Printf;;

let () =
  for i = 0 to Array.length Sys.argv - 1 do
    printf "[%i] %s\n" i Sys.argv.(i)
  done;;
```

is there a way to step through the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, after starting the debugger, you have to set the arguments, eg

```
(ocd) set arguments "a" "b" "C"
(ocd) r
```

Comment: There is also another way: `ocamldebug [options] program [arguments]`.
The arguments following *program* are optional, and are passed as command-line arguments to the program being debugged ([source](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/debugger.html)).

Comment: documentation bug?