# How to launch program with arguments in ocamldebug?

Tags: ocaml, ocamldebug

I want to give ocamldebug a try. How can I run a program in it with a set of arguments? I can't find anything related in the reference documentation.[1]

In GDB, I would enter `run arg1...argn`. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in ocamldebug.

```
$ ocamldebug server.byte 
    OCaml Debugger version 4.04.0

(ocd) run -i 127.0.0.1 -p 8080
Syntax error.
(ocd)
```

Entering `help run` doesn't give much information:

```
(ocd) help run
run: run the program from current position.
```

1. https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/debugger.html

Comment: If you use [Tuareg](https://github.com/ocaml/tuareg), they will be asked in the minibuffer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command line arguments to ocamldebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41128840/command-line-arguments-to-ocamldebug)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs:

> ocamldebug [options] program [arguments]
>
> **The arguments following program are optional, and are passed as
>   command-line arguments to the program being debugged.** (See also the
>   set arguments command.)

In debugger, you can use `set arguments -i 127.0.0.1 -p 8080` command.